# How to maintain concurrency and lock for particular seat reservation in e-commerce application using jax-rs?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jersey, jax-rs

I am building an e-commerce which requires concurrency management and lock for particular time on specific seats which user want to reserve. How can I imlpement this approach in my application.And is their any way to apply lock on columns in database to achieve this.
I am using jersey services to imlement this application

Comment: Database locks on columns  are possible but normally only when using database transactions. However, this could lead to deadlocks and should be avoided (it's not applicable in your scenario). Simply, have a LOCKED column in your DB and some code (possibly a batch program) that will, at scheduled intervals, unlock this column (depending on the interval passed). The LOCKED column may simply hold Y (locked) and N (unlocked)